# MVC 4, How to populate 3 textboxs when Autocomplete value is selected?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I have this form which has a text box and I have already attached autocomplete to it, but i dont know how to trigger the ActionResult(it returns json) when the value is selected and grab the json result and put it into textboxes.
Beside that in the same form I have a drop down list, I want when I select a value the blow dropdown list is populated and also the other 3 textboxes?

This is the JSON result returned when a drop down list is selected :

> [{"Price":112,"Discount":0,"ProductTypeList":[{"ProductTypeId":3,"ProductId":1,"UserId":2,"Type":"1 Kg","FLEX_FLD1":null,"FLEX_FLD2":null,"FLEX_FLD3":null,"FLEX_FLD4":null,"FLEX_FLD5":null}],"Disounttype":"Percentage"}]

`ProductTypeList` items are the ones I want to put into second `dropdownlist` and Price,Discount and Percentage into 3 `textboxes`.

Appreciate your help.

EDIT:

```
 <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerNo)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerNo, new { @data_cdp_autocomplete = @Url.Action("Autocomplete") })
    @Html.ActionLink("Add New A Customer", "CreateCustomer", "Customer")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerNo)
</div>
<div id="ShopList">          
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerAddress)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerAddress)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerAddress)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerPAACI)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerPAACI)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerPAACI)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemName)
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
<select name="SelectProduct" class="SelectProduct">
    <option value="0">SELECT PRODUCT</option>
    @*Iterating Category ViewModel *@
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {         
        <option value="@item.ProductId">@item.ItemName
        </option>                               
    }
    <option value="00">Other</option>
    </select>
   </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Item Size")
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        <select name="SelectSize" class="SelectSize">
            <option value="0">SELECT SIZE</option>
            <option value="00">Other</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>

  var submitAutocompleteForm = function (event, ui) {

    var $input = $(this);
    $input.val(ui.item.label);

    var $form = $input.parents("form:first");
    $form.submit();
};

var createAutocomplete = function () {
    var $input = $(this);

    var options = {
        source: $input.attr("data-cdp-autocomplete"),
        select: submitAutocompleteForm
    };

    $input.autocomplete(options);
};

$("form[data-cdp-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);
$("input[data-cdp-autocomplete]").each(createAutocomplete);
```

This is located in js file, and refreshes the page after submit the first form, which is not a good idea.

I am new with jquery. could you please show me some solution jquery for this to fit this scenario.

Comment: Could you show the view/page and your code JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to populate three text-boxes, when something event occurred in your view:

You can do this simply like this,

```
<div class="three-textbox">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="editor-label">
                price
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="text" id="price" name="price" />
                </div>
                 <div class="editor-label">
                discount
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="text" id="discount" name="discount" />
                </div>
                 <div class="editor-label">
                percentage
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="text" id="percentage" name="percentage" />
                </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
```

Jquery code would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".three-textbox").hide();
});

$('.dropone').change(function() {  //event changed function   
  $(".three-textbox").slideDown(); **OR** $(".three-textbox").show();
});
```